# Leafletjs popups in iframe not working in IE11

Tags: wms, leaflet, getfeatureinfo, internet-explorer

This is my leafletjs iframe in a wordpress blog: http://www.kemeling-consulting.com/cresh-map-viewer/

The iframe is working fine in firefox and chrome, in IE11 the popups are not working. They are getfeatureinfo requests from the geoserver WMS.

The website also works fine (popups work ok) in IE11 directly: http://185.19.29.113:8080/cresh_map/mapla.html

I added this in the header.php file

Does anybody know what else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be related to [the bug described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370482/preventing-script5-access-is-denied-error-in-ie), since I get the same `SCRIPT5: Access is denied` error in the console in IE11, and you are using jQuery 1.10.1.

You can either downgrade to 1.10.0, or use a version from 1.10.2 and up, [as described in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371187/1193155). You can also try the latest version which I believe is 1.11.2.

Not sure why this would cause an issue in the iFrame and not otherwise, but easy to fix and try again.

Note: I also get an error in the Chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined`. You may want to also remove the reference to init() on `<body onload="init()">` in mapla.html line 18 since apparently this function does not exist.